# Is it possible to "send" parameters to shared steps in MTM?

Tags: testcase, mtm, test-creation

I want to know if is possible to pass parameters values to shared steps in MTM?

I have one product that have the same test cases as other but the values of the expected results are different. So it would be really useful if I can create share steps that receive parameters values from the test case that use it

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You provide values for the parameters in the test cases where the shared steps are used.

You don’t have to provide values in the shared steps definition. However, you can provide one default row of values, which is used when you create an action recording of a standalone shared step.